# ls() the column of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a C developper trying to learn R, and there's a few things I can't wrap my head around.

I've tried doing something as simple as listing the elements from an int list stored in a data frame.

For this exemple, I'm using the data `mpg` from package `ggplot2`.

```
data(mpg, package="ggplot2")
```

Doing `ls()` on the `mpg` data frame lists the elements stored in it.

```
> ls(mpg)
[1] "class"        "cty"          "cyl"          "displ"        "drv"          "fl"           "hwy"          "manufacturer"
[9] "model"        "trans"        "year"
```

Accessing a column can be done by giving it's name as string to the data frame.

```
> mpg["hwy"]
# A tibble: 234 x 1
     hwy
   <int>
 1    29
 2    29
 3    31
 4    30
 5    26
 6    26
 7    27
 8    26
 9    25
10    28
# ... with 224 more rows
```

But using `ls()` on the column doesn't return the list of int stored in it.

```
> ls(mpg["hwy"])
[1] "hwy"
```

I'm really hitting a wall there. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work the way I'm expecting to, but I can't find any information. That probably means that what I thought I've understood about R is wrong.

Can anyone please give me any directions about that?

Best regards.

Comment: `?ls` will immediately show you: `ls and objects return a vector of character strings giving the names of the objects in the specified environment.`

Comment: Are you looking for `mpg[["hwy"]]`? You might want to study `help("[")`.

Comment: Do you mean list the column names? If so, `colnames(mpg)` or `names(mpg)` work. Or do you mean get the vector of `mpg[["hwy"]]`? If so, that will work and so will `mpg$hwy`. Read up on subsetting, it is complex but powerful: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: I understand better now. Both answers from @hpesoj626  and @Roland helped me there.

I've misunderstood the role of `ls()` and tried to combine it with `mpg[["hwy"]]` at some point.

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @dash2 I wanted to get the vector of `mpg[["hwy"]]`.
I'm still struggling with the new definitions of data structures in R.
Thank you very much for that alternative way.